# Schoof algorithm with division polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Please help me understand one aspect of Schoof's algorithm. Suppose there is a curve $y ^ 2 = x ^ 3 + 2x + 1$, $P = 19$ The array of primes, according to the algorithm, is: $\{2, 3, 5\}$ The problem arises when calculating $k = 19 \pmod 5$. Since $| k | < 5/2$, then we take $-1$ from the values $-1$ and $4$. For calculations, I use division polynomials. At the stage of calculating lambda, I get formulas. But some of the division polynomials have indices $-2$ and $-3$. As far as I know, division polynomials are numbered starting at $-1$. What to do with polynomials with indices $-2$ and $-3$?

I calculate lambda using formulas: [image: Formulas for lambda]

After that, I execute the body of the loop: [image: Algorithm]

1. $\gcd(x^p - x, x^3 + 2x + 1) = 1$, where $p = 19$. And it means that $t1 = 1 \pmod 2$
2. $k = 19 \pmod 3 = 1$. $|k| < 3/2$. $\gcd(x^p - x, F3) = x+11 \neq 1$. Since result is not equal $1$, we can use TonelliShanks algorittm to find $w$. $w = 1$. $\gcd(4x^3+10x^2+2x+13, F3) = 6x + 9 \neq 1$.
3. Since $\gcd(4x^3+10x^2+2x+13, F3) \neq 1$, I define the sign of $w$: $\gcd(6x^3 + 15^2 + 14x - 2, F3) = 2x + 3 \neq 1$. It means that $w$ is positive. $t2 = 2 * w \pmod 3$. I get $t2 = 2 \pmod 3$
4. $k = 19 \pmod 5 = 4 = -1$. |$k| < 5/2$. That's why I take $k = -1$. But I can't find $x, y$ using division polynomials with $k < 0$. If I take $k = 4$, I get for $1\leq tau \leq 3$ that $\gcd(*\text{polynom, created with $k = 4$}*, F5) = 1$. And I get answer $0 \pmod 5$. But I must get $2 \pmod 5$. Futher I need to define sign: $t3 = 2 \pmod 5$ or $t3 = -2 \pmod 5$
   As a result I must get:
   $t = 1 \pmod 2$,
   $t = 2 \pmod 3$,
   $t = -2 \pmod 5$

But I get:
$t = 1 \pmod 2$,
$t = 2 \pmod 3$,
$t = 0 \pmod 5$

It is wrong.

I get F3 and F5  using formulas:[image: Division polynomials]

Comment: Right now this question is missing context and it's likely to be closed and downvoted. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on meta for information and advice on improving this post.

Comment: Someone is going to ask you to use tex/mathjax, so it might as well be me. It is much easier to read, and you can type any formulas you want.

Comment: Good job on the mathJax-ing! Some quick tips: use `\leq` and `\geq` for $\leq$ and $\geq$, `\gcd(a, b)` to get $\gcd(a, b)$, and `a\pmod{x}` to get $a\pmod{x}$ (which look much clearer/neater than $GCD(a, b)$ and $0(mod5)$, etc.).

Comment: I made some edits to your latex, but wasn't sure about the =>. Are they meant to be $\geq$ or $\Rightarrow$? (Use `\geq` or `\Rightarrow` for these.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. It is necessary to take the |k| for negative values of k and adjust the formulas a little.